# Сколько бит нужно для записи порядка 32 элементов?

Tags: алгоритм, комбинаторика

Есть исходный порядок 32 элементов: `0,1,2...31`

Их перемешали. **Нужен способ** записать их новый порядок, занимающий минимум объёма.

Совсем в лоб: по 5 бит для каждого элемента = 160 бит (20 байт).

Некруто. С каждой «установленной» позицией, число вариантов для оставшихся сокращается. Последнему эл-ту вообще не нужно указывать позицию: осталось одно «парковочное место».

Нулевому эл-ту надо все 5 бит, чтобы обозначить одну из 32 позиций. Следующему (первому) – из 31, но то же 5 бит, хотя уже появился избыток в один вариант. Так до 15-го: `16*5`. Дальше из 16 позиций выбираем – достаточно 4 бит. 16-23: `8*4` бит. Дальше из 8: `4*3` бит. Потом `2*2` и `1`. Итого `16*5 + 8*4 + 4*3 + 2*2 + 1*1 + 0*0 = 129 бит`

А может, есть более оптимальный вариант, сводящий к нулю избыточность записи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всего возможно 32! новых порядков. Их можно перенумеровать (например, [так](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm)), и каждую из перестановок идентифицировать её номером.

Итого нужно `ceil(log_2 (32!))` бит. (Калькулятор вроде бы говорит, 118.) Это, по идее, теоретический минимум.

Comment: 118 битам равно это выражение

Comment: @igumnov: опередили :)

Comment: Это ты меня опередил, хотел тоже самое ответить.

Comment: @igumnov: Сорри!

Comment: у меня 117 [получилось](http://ideone.com/IxUDeB) )

Comment: @Sergiks: Если биты начинаются с 0, получается 118 штук (0 .. 117)